# Is there any relation between a Conservative vector field and a conservative dynamic system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, dynamical-systems, vector-fields

Given $y,f: \mathbb{R^{+}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ consider the fist order ODE system:

$\overset{.}{y}=f(y(t),t)$

We know that thas System is conservative if the divergence of $f$ (given it's exists) is null.

We also know that the vector field of the tangent vectors given by $f$ is conservative iff exists a function such that it's gradient is $f$.

Is there any relation between these two definitions?